Visual Studio Code how to resolve merge conflicts with syncthing
Is there a way to resolve merge conflics from syncthing in VS code.
Syncthings conflicts look like this.
<filename>.sync-conflict-<date>-<time>-<modifiedBy>.<ext>
There are two fysical files. I would like to start it from the context menu in windows explorer
